# What does it mean that we need $_0$ induction to prove PA consistency?

Tags: logic, induction, ordinals, peano-axioms

I have started to learn about Peano Arithmetic, and also about ordinals.
In particular, I have seen that the Goodstein theorem is an example of a statement that can be expressed in PA but that requires other axioms to be proven.
In particular, ZFC axioms (or just ZF?) let us construct ordinals up to $_0$ and with those we can prove Goodstein theorem.

I have also read that the statement $Cons(PA)$ is expressible in PA itself but cannot be proved in PA (that's Gödel theorem) but that it can be proved with $_0$ induction.

Now my questions are:

- What does it really mean that it can be proved with $_0$ induction? I mean, are there specific axioms we can add to PA to express $_0$ induction or does it just mean that we can prove it in ZFC with the help of $_0$ induction, just like Goodstein's theorem?
- Also, in simple words, what's the idea of such a proof?

Comment: See [Gentzen's consistency proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof): "Gentzen showed that the consistency of the first-order Peano axioms is provable over the base theory of primitive recursive arithmetic with the additional principle of quantifier-free transfinite induction up to the ordinal $\epsilon_0$."

Comment: In a nutshell, the meta-theory uses a "weaker theory": PRA, supplemented with a stronger induction principle: transfinite induction, used to manage induction on the proof tree of the basic theory .